# Finite Transformation of the Special Conformal Transformation

Tags: group-theory, conformal-field-theory

In numerous discussion of the special conformal transformation, they cite the finite transformation as

$${x^\mu}'=\frac{x^\mu-b^\mu x^2}{1-2x\cdot b+b^2 x^2}$$

This can be found from integrating the infinitesimal conformal transformation

$$\delta x^\mu =2(b\cdot x)x^\mu-x\cdot x b^\mu$$

I found the derivation [given as an answer on this site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121920/integrating-the-generator-of-the-infinitesimal-special-conformal-transformation). I completely understand what they did, but at the end of the day they get the answer to be

$$x(t)=\frac{x_0-x^2_0 (tb)}{1-2x_0(tb)+x_0^2(tb)^2}$$

Their starting point was the differential equation $\dot{x}=2(b\cdot x)x-x^2 b$.

Why, exactly, is there a $t$ in the second equation but no $t$ in the first? Is $tb=b^\mu$? Also, where in the derivation I've cited do they only consider the case of $\mu=0$ (i.e., time)? Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @CosmasZachos That was a typo--thank you for pointing that out. I've edited the post appropriately. I followed the derivation out completely and I believe I understand it, but I don't understand why the final result given in that answer differs from the result in my textbooks.

Comment: $t=|b|$, that is, $b^\mu\equiv \hat{b}^\mu t$.

Comment: But is it different? why did you *not* reinstate the 4-indices μ in the last displayed equation you wrote, so $x(t)^\mu =...$ and the parametric diff eqn (s)  that led to it?

Comment: Also, Josh is not considering $\mu=0$ only. He is suppressing the indices, so the vector equation $x=y$ is equivalent to $x^\mu=y^\mu$.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I was quoting the result from the linked answer which didn't have the superscripts. That's why I was confused--they solved the equation in a different notation, and that's what's confusing me. Also, in their solution they have $\dot{y}=-b$, so $y=y_0-bt$. Would this still mean that $b=|t|$? Are all derivatives technically taken with respect to $|b|$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Trimok solved the problem most elegantly in his comment to the question cited, and since you are troubled by  @Josh's simplifying changes of variables, $b^\mu\equiv \hat{b}~  t$,
I'll avoid them to merely integrate the variation
$$\delta x^\mu =2(b\cdot x)x^\mu-x\cdot x~ b^\mu$$
directly. It immediately implies
$$\delta \left (\frac{ x^\mu}{x^2}\right)  = \frac{ \delta x^\mu}{x^2} -2 x^\mu \frac{ x\cdot \delta x }{x^4} = -b^\mu ~.$$

That is, the vector $x^\mu/x^2$ evolves by shifting along $-\hat{b}^\mu$, linearly in the magnitude $|b|$ of $b^\mu$, so with constant unit speed  in this "pseudotime"  $|b|$. Integrating this simplest of advections for finite pseudotime, we immediately get
$$
 \frac{ x'^\mu}{x'^2}=  \frac{ x^\mu}{x^2}   -b^\mu .
$$ 
Square both sides, to get the normalization,
$$
\frac{ 1}{x'^2}=  \frac{1}{x^2}   +b^2 -2\frac{ x\cdot b}{x^2}=  \frac{1-2x\cdot b+b^2 x^2 }{x^2}, 
$$
which divides the above vector equation to yield your conventional form for it, ∴
$${x^\mu}'=\frac{x^\mu-b^\mu x^2}{1-2x\cdot b+b^2 x^2}~.$$